# Python flask - Encoding links based on JSON varibale

Tags: python, json, hyperlink, urllib, encode

I'm creating an application in Python flask and I'm struggling to encode my links. In my HTML template I'm calling data from JSON and based on a variable from JSON, I want to create a link to another page but the variables that have "space" in them, only take the first word and the link doesn't work as it should.

This is my JSON:

```
[
   {
      "team":"AFC Bournemouth"
   },
   {
      "team":"Arsenal"
   }
]
```

And this is my python:

```
@app.route('/<team>/')
def artist(team):
    json_data=open('static/data.json').read()
    data= json.loads(json_data)
    urllib.quote_plus(data.team)
    return render_template("team.html", team=team)
```

I'm trying to use "urllib.quote_plus" but I get an error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'team'

I don't know how to fix it.

And this is my loop in html:

```
{% for data in results %}
    <div class="team">
        <p><a href=/{{ data.team }}>{{ data.team }}</a></p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Before I used "urllib.quote_plus" the link for "Arsenal" worked perfect, but for "AFC Bournemouth" it only took the word "AFC".

Answer (score 0):

That is strange that it is working correctly for "Arsenal". Actually you should iterate over the "data" because it is a list

Example:

```
@app.route('/<team>/')
def artist(team):
    json_data=open('static/data.json').read()
    data= json.loads(json_data)
    data = [{'team': urllib.quote_plus(team['team'])} for team in data]
    return render_template("team.html", results=data)
```

Another thing is that in render_template you are sending variable team and not results (changed in my example). This way it should be fine and work with your Jinja template.

Edit: changed list comprehension

Comment: Can you write what kind of bug you have?

Comment: I just realized that I write code wrongly, now it should work fine

Comment: Ok the code works as it encodes the variable, but it doesn't encode the link which is what Im after. I want to display the variable from JSON, but when the variable is clicked, it is being encoded by python so the link is correct.